# Include NOT .NET cpp and h in .NET application

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, visual-c++

Editors Note: The question appears to be asking:

> Can I write non-managed ("regular") C++ code and then use it in a managed (".NET") application?

The original question text:

> Sorry for the stupid question, but... Can I create cpp and h files with the NOT .NET functions and after that use these functions in .NET application (I need to use h and cpp files that use opencv in .NET application)?
>   Sorry for my english

Comment: Are you asking if you can write non-managed ("regular") C++ code and then use it in a managed (".NET") application?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile the source code to a dll and then reference it from your .net project.

Comment: Not the only solution, but at least clean.